# how to normalize thousand of weights in neural network?

Tags: neural-network

I have this back propagation problem where in I have thousand of weights per layer(20k). My problem lies before I use the activation function where in the sum of all (inputs * weights) value for  certain node reaches 1k to 2k and still increasing. I know that I should expect that the ranges of the sum should be in "activation range" for the sigmoid function to be acceptable.

Is there a way that I can do so that the sum should be around within -35 to 35 and not to 1k or 2k+? The latter values influence my output layer nodes to always give a value of "1"(if postive 1k or 2k) or "0"(if negative 1k or 2k).

I tested my back propagation in smaller case which always work but not on larger scale.

Comment: It sounds like there might be a problem with your back prop implementation. If your sigmoid fires in error then shouldn't your learning passes gradually adjust the weights downward until that doesn't happen?

Comment: Is there any formula wherein I can normalize my inputs and weights? I don't want the sum to shoot to bigger values. I want the sum to be in "activation range"of sigmoid( somewhere between -35 to +35).

Comment: How are you initializing your weights? Have you tried initializing with N(0, std), where std can follow Glorot and Bengio's suggestion 2 / (incoming nodes + outgoing nodes)?